# can't copy the input field value inside iframe on iOS5

Tags: ios5, mobile, input, safari, zepto

I can't copy input field value.

I tried this steps.

1. focus input field
2. hold and tap select all
3. tap copy

[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/wYMKE/4/)　can copy text. (not load Zepto.js)

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/wYMKE/5/)　can't copy text. (load Zepto.js)

I think the reason lies with Zepto.

Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'm not sure if I understand your problem or your attempted solution since you didn't post any code, but with Zepto (or jQuery) you get input values like so:

```
var userInput = $('#input_id').val()
// then you can do whatever with it, like writing it to an alert
alert(userInput)
```

Comment: My English is very poor, and I can not explain well in detail...
But, thanks for your clarification.